# Count the number of occurrence of string in a large file

Tags: grep

I have a large 900MB xml file and the entire file is just one lines. There is no line break between tags. I need to count the occurence of a particular tag in that file.

I tried

```
grep -o '<start tag>' filename | wc -l
```

i get a `grep: line too long` error.

How can I get around this?

Comment: tried sed 's/<test>/<test>\n/g' test.log | grep -c "<test>". but this again when i do grep it works for small file but in my case the grep gives the too long error

Comment: @md1980 is it `grep` or `sed` that gives that error in that case (your last comment).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of a hack:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN { $/ = ">"; $c = 0 } $c++ if /<start tag>/; END { print "$c\n" }' filename
```

The idea is to loop over "lines" that are terminated by `>` instead of `\n` (newline). That should avoid "line too long" errors.

Comment: @Kusalananda No, the `BEGIN` block runs first (at parse time, actually).

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
awk -F'<start tag>' '{print NF-1}' file
```

If that fails, you can do this with GNU awk (for multi-char RS):

```
awk -v RS='<start tag>' 'END{print NR-1}' file
```